# How to add User Token from Flutter to Django Rest Framework to avoid Forbidden access

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project I have created an api_service.dart which sends username and password and returns back with the Token authorization.

I am currently not able to send the authorization Token in the header to allow fetching information from dj-rest-auth/user and I am getting `Forbidden: /api/dj-rest-auth/user/`

Here is the `api_service.dart`:

```
class APIService {
  static var client = http.Client();

  static Future<bool> login(
    LoginRequestModel model,
  ) async {
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    var url = Uri.parse(
      Config.apiURL + Config.loginAPI,
    );
    print(url);

    var response = await client.post(
      url,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      body: jsonEncode(model.toJson()),
    );
    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      await SharedService.setLoginDetails(
        loginResponseJson(
          response.body,
        ),
      );
      print(response.body);

      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Here is the function to call the user details:

```
Future<User> fetchUser() async {
  final response = await http.get("url");
  Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': loginResponseJson(response.body),
  };

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {

    return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load User');
  }
}
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
error: The element type 'LoginResponseModel' can't be assigned to the map value type 'String'.
```

the loginResponseJson(response.body):

```
{"key":"............."}
```

**My Question:**

What is the best way to add the token to the header to allow user authentication to fetch data from Django Rest Framework.  How can I fix this error?

Comment: What exact result of **loginResponseJson(response.body)** function?

Comment: the issue is not with the header token, you're doing wrong in this line `` await SharedService.setLoginDetails(
        loginResponseJson(
          response.body,
        ),
      );``

Comment: @powerman23rus the response is the token key

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to store access token into SharedPreferences first. Then, for every request, you fetch this token from store and add to header. Currently, I use chopper for https generator as:

```
class AuthenticatedClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final http.Client _inner;
  final FlutterSecureStorage secureStorage;

  AuthenticatedClient(this._inner, {required this.secureStorage});

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(
    http.BaseRequest request,
  ) async {
    if (request.headers["Content-Type"] != null) {
      request.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    }

    final token = await secureStorage.read(key: PrefKeys.accessToken);
    if (token != null) {
      request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
    }

    return _inner.send(request);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `Authorization` header has a valid structure

```
Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ${your_token}',
```

};